# Custom css class does not apply for a tooltip in Angular Material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, tooltip, angular-material-15

After updating Angular Material until version 15 I lost a possibility to apply coloring to the material tooltip.

This is a code in .html:

```
    <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Tooltip message" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip">
      <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

This code is not working with MatTooltipModule importing in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```

However it works correct with legacy importing (which I want to get rid off):

```
import { MatLegacyTooltipModule as MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-tooltip';
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Selectors have changed, try remaking them.

Comment: @mgx sorry, which selectors changed? Code above is a code from official documentation https://v15.material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples#tooltip-custom-class. It works for the mentioned ` text-transform: uppercase;` but doesn't work for coloring

Answer (score -1):

Check this one.

```
   ::ng-deep.mat-mdc-tooltip {
--mdc-plain-tooltip-container-color: #ff4141;
--mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-color: #000;
```

}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mamxg3-tsjszm?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts